# PHP Remove Query and Encode

Tags: php, mysql, url

I am trying to do some work to tidy up my urls but am having a few problems with the php.I need to encode it so that the plus signs are underscores, remove the .php and then remove the query ?page= all together. So ideally the url would be:

www.mysite.com/blog/blog_heading

Currently my string for the a tag is:

$str = urlencode('blog.php?page=' . ($row['blog_heading']));

Which results in:

www.mysite.com/blog.php%3Fpage%3Dblog+heading

Sorry if there is a lot here for one question but I have no idea where to go with this.

Thanks

I think I have figured out the rewrite but it dosent seem to be working..

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ blog.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ blog.php?page=$1

Comment: preg_replace(), mod_rewrite - research

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is the rewrite I came up with, RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ blog.php?page=$1 but it doesn't seem to be working, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't urlencode the `'blog.php?page=` Just urlencode the values.

In other words:

```
$str = 'blog.php?page=' . urlencode($row['blog_heading']);
```